# java-why synchronized block is not giving correct result with loop

Tags: java, multithreading

i have written a code that created several thread and start it. i locked monitor on object using synchronized block.i expected that the first thread created should lock the object and completes its work. then any other object can enter it.

but its not occurring, program is below.

```
class ThreadCreationDemo implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {   
                System.out.println("i: "+i+" thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" threadgroup: "+Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup()+" "+Thread.holdsLock(this));
                try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {   
                    System.out.println(e.toString());   
                }           
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         Thread t[]=new Thread[5];

         for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
         {
             t[i]=new Thread(new ThreadCreationDemo());
             t[i].start();
         }
    }
}
```

i expect the result should be like this.

first the all values for i=0 to 9 is printed under a thread name say thread 0
then thread 1 etc.

but the output is like this:

```
i: 0 thread: Thread-1
i: 0 thread: Thread-3
i: 0 thread: Thread-2
i: 0 thread: Thread-0
i: 0 thread: Thread-4
i: 1 thread: Thread-1
i: 1 thread: Thread-4
i: 1 thread: Thread-3
i: 1 thread: Thread-0
i: 1 thread: Thread-2
i: 2 thread: Thread-1
i: 2 thread: Thread-3
i: 2 thread: Thread-2
i: 2 thread: Thread-0
i: 2 thread: Thread-4
i: 3 thread: Thread-1
i: 3 thread: Thread-3
i: 3 thread: Thread-0
i: 3 thread: Thread-4
i: 3 thread: Thread-2
i: 4 thread: Thread-1
i: 4 thread: Thread-3
i: 4 thread: Thread-2
i: 4 thread: Thread-4
i: 4 thread: Thread-0
i: 5 thread: Thread-1
i: 5 thread: Thread-4
i: 5 thread: Thread-3
```

Answer (score 6):

Problem is you are creating new object everytime : `new ThreadCreationDemo()`

So all threads obtain lock on different objects, hence locking will fail.

Answer (score 3):

You are synchronizing on

```
synchronized(this)
```

In other words, each instance is locking on itself. You're not locking on a shared object.

A solution is to lock on a static object shared by all class instances. For example

```
synchronized (ThreadCreationDemo.class) {...}
```

Or, when creating the `Thread`, pass in a shared object reference which each `Thread` can synchronize on.

```
new ThreadCreationDemo(new Object());
...
public ThreadCreationDemo(Object o) {
    this.lock = o
}

public void run () {
    synchronized (lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```